# TYPO3 verson 11 backend Login is not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have installed TYPO3 version 11.2.0. Installation completed successfully. The front end is working, Install tool is working. But I can't Login to the Backend.

The Login page is there but when I click on the button, It will show the error:https://prnt.sc/1991vu7

This seems like something related to the sites configuration. But I have done that.

```
base: 'http://sample/t3v11/'
errorHandling: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-us
    direction: ltr
    flag: us
rootPageId: 1
routes: {  }
```

My htaccess file:

```
    #####
#
# Example .htaccess file for TYPO3 CMS - for use with Apache Webserver
#
# This file includes settings for the following configuration options:
#
# - Compression
# - Caching
# - MIME types
# - Cross Origin requests
# - Rewriting and Access
# - Miscellaneous
# - PHP optimisation
#
# If you want to use it, you have to copy it to the root folder of your TYPO3 installation (if its
# not there already) and rename it to '.htaccess'. To make .htaccess files work, you might need to
# adjust the 'AllowOverride' directive in your Apache configuration file.
#
# IMPORTANT: You may need to change this file depending on your TYPO3 installation!
#            Consider adding this file's content to your webserver's configuration directly for speed improvement
#
# Lots of the options are taken from https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess
#
####


### Begin: Compression ###

# Compressing resource files will save bandwidth and so improve loading speed especially for users
# with slower internet connections. TYPO3 can compress the .js and .css files for you.
# *) Uncomment the following lines and
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 for the Backend
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 together with the TypoScript properties
#    config.compressJs and config.compressCss for GZIP compression of Frontend JS and CSS files.

#<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
#   AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
#   AddType "text/css" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#AddEncoding gzip .gzip

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
    #
    # (!) For Apache versions below version 2.3.7 you don't need to
    # enable `mod_filter` and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>`
    # and `</IfModule>` lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in
    # the core directives.
    #
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
            application/javascript \
            application/json \
            application/ld+json \
            application/manifest+json \
            application/rdf+xml \
            application/rss+xml \
            application/schema+json \
            application/vnd.geo+json \
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
            application/x-font-ttf \
            application/x-javascript \
            application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
            application/xhtml+xml \
            application/xml \
            font/eot \
            font/opentype \
            image/bmp \
            image/svg+xml \
            image/vnd.microsoft.icon \
            image/x-icon \
            text/cache-manifest \
            text/css \
            text/html \
            text/javascript \
            text/plain \
            text/vcard \
            text/vnd.rim.location.xloc \
            text/vtt \
            text/x-component \
            text/x-cross-domain-policy \
            text/xml
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip svgz
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

### End: Compression ###



### Begin: Browser caching of resource files ###

# This affects Frontend and Backend and increases performance.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>

### End: Browser caching of resource files ###


### Begin: MIME types ###

# Proper MIME types for all files
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # Security configuration
    RemoveType .html .htm
    <FilesMatch ".+\.html?$">
        AddType text/html .html .htm
    </FilesMatch>

    RemoveType .svg .svgz
    <FilesMatch ".+\.svgz?$">
        AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
    </FilesMatch>

    # Data interchange
    AddType application/atom+xml                        atom
    AddType application/json                            json map topojson
    AddType application/ld+json                         jsonld
    AddType application/rss+xml                         rss
    AddType application/vnd.geo+json                    geojson
    AddType application/xml                             rdf xml

    # JavaScript
    AddType application/javascript                      js

    # Manifest files
    AddType application/manifest+json                   webmanifest
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache

    # Media files

    AddType audio/mp4                                   f4a f4b m4a
    AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg opus
    AddType image/bmp                                   bmp
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType video/mp4                                   f4v f4p m4v mp4
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv
    AddType image/x-icon                                cur ico

    # Web fonts
    AddType font/woff                                   woff
    AddType font/woff2                                  woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot
    AddType font/ttf                                    ttc ttf
    AddType font/otf                                    otf

    # Other
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-bb-appworld                   bbaw
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType text/vcard                                  vcard vcf
    AddType text/vnd.rim.location.xloc                  xloc
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc

</IfModule>

# UTF-8 encoding
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .manifest .rdf .rss .vtt .webapp .webmanifest .xml
</IfModule>

### End: MIME types ###



### Begin: Cross Origin ###

# Send the CORS header for images when browsers request it.
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Allow cross-origin access to web fonts.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

### End: Cross Origin ###



### Begin: Rewriting and Access ###

# You need rewriting, if you use a URL-Rewriting extension (RealURL, CoolUri).

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Enable URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On
    

    # Store the current location in an environment variable CWD to use
    # mod_rewrite in .htaccess files without knowing the RewriteBase
    RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=CWD:%2]

    # Rules to set ApplicationContext based on hostname
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production/Staging]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production]

    # Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
    # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
    # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
    # IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ %{ENV:CWD}$1.$3 [L]

    # Access block for folders
    RewriteRule _(?:recycler|temp)_/ - [F]
    RewriteRule fileadmin/templates/.*\.(?:txt|ts)$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^(?:vendor|typo3_src|typo3temp/var) - [F]
    RewriteRule (?:typo3conf/ext|typo3/sysext|typo3/ext)/[^/]+/(?:Configuration|Resources/Private|Tests?|Documentation|docs?)/ - [F]

    # Block access to all hidden files and directories with the exception of
    # the visible content from within the `/.well-known/` hidden directory (RFC 5785).
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule (?:^|/)\. - [F]

    # Stop rewrite processing, if we are in any other known directory
    # NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
    RewriteRule ^(?:fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/) - [L]

    # If the file/symlink/directory does not exist but is below /typo3/, redirect to the TYPO3 Backend entry point.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/typo3/.*$
    RewriteRule ^typo3/(.*)$ %{ENV:CWD}typo3/index.php [QSA,L]

    # If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
    # For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# Access block for files
# Apache < 2.3
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    <FilesMatch "(?i:^\.|^#.*#|^(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|^composer\.(?:json|lock)|^ext_conf_template\.txt|^ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|^ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|tsconfig|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sqlite(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*|rc)|.*~)$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# Apache ≥ 2.3
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#(?i:/\.|/\x23.*\x23|/(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|/composer\.(?:json|lock)|/ext_conf_template\.txt|/ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|/ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|tsconfig|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sqlite(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*|rc)|.*~)$#">
        Require all denied
    </If>
</IfModule>

# Block access to vcs directories
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 404 /\.(?:git|svn|hg)/
</IfModule>

### End: Rewriting and Access ###



### Begin: Miscellaneous ###

# 404 error prevention for non-existing redirected folders
Options -MultiViews

# Make sure that directory listings are disabled.
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Force IE to render pages in the highest available mode
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svgz?|ttf|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|woff2?|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

    # Reducing MIME type security risks
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

# ETag removal
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None

### End: Miscellaneous ###


# Add your own rules here.
```

Anyone, please help me to find out the issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Most probably you did not configure your webserver properly. For Apache a default .htaccess is created with the correct configuration if this file wasn't there during the setup. For other webservers check the docs at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/In-depth/SystemRequirements/Index.html#nginx, search for "TYPO3 Backend URLs"

Comment: `/typo3/index.php` should not be answered by TYPO3s PageNotFound-Handler... Maybe your access-log can show you which URL is called.

Comment: I'm attached my .htaccess file with the question. I couldn't find anything wrong with that. Do you?

Comment: Did you use your own htaccess or is it generated by TYPO3? In TYPO3 11, the backend routing is introduced, meaning that htaccesses from TYPO3 10 or 9 wont work

Comment: same htaccess generated by typo3 itself.Actually, my issue is solved. I have pointed a subdomain to this